# Marital relationship during pregnancy

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara

My wife is bleeding, and is about 8 weeks pregnant we feel that maybe during intercourse we caused harm, is there any Halacha on sex during pregnancy ?

Comment: If she has any health concern, then she should contact her obstetrician or a clinic or hospital.

Comment: Is this a medical or halachic question?

Comment: DanF  both, it's a medical question on Halacha, or what is the Halacha in the medical situation。

Comment: If she is bleeding it might be forbidden for (5+)7 days even though she is pregnant

Comment: I dont think Mi Yodeya is the place to ask personal questions. Please seek Medical and Rabbinic counsel asap!

Comment: @bondonk I've seen many questions on this website that don't even seem worth asking, and u want to comment like that on this one? All our questions are for personal growth in Torah and Halacha, when we feel stuck or would like additional opinions or facts, we ask. Maybe you should grow some sense, of course we have Doctor assistance, now I seek Jewish counsel, and I must put up with snobs like you.

Comment: @david macias jr I'm sorry if you took my comment emotionally as an attack on you. It wasn't meant to be, of course. But as a policy on this forum personal questions of this nature are not answered and should certainly not be taken as psak. You framed your question as a personal one - I'm concerned that you should use the answer as psak. Asking the question more generally will alleviate this e.g. "if a woman has health problem of bleeding during sex how does a couple reconcile sexual relations?"

Comment: @bondonk I will note your response, my question and situation is a real one, I am fairly new, active wise, to this site, I am a little relieved to read you have responded fairly well to my reply, sometimes my questions are not accepted due to the format standards, and this format was accepted, I will try to use your example format first next time, by the way what is psak?

Comment: @david macias jr. Psak loosely translate as "halachic ruling"

Answer (score 3):

See Gemara Nidda 31a about conjugal relationship during pregnancy:

> תנו רבנן שלשה חדשים הראשונים תשמיש קשה לאשה וגם קשה לולד אמצעיים קשה לאשה ויפה לולד אחרונים יפה לאשה ויפה לולד שמתוך כך נמצא הולד מלובן ומזורז תנא המשמש מטתו ליום תשעים כאילו שופך דמים מנא ידע אלא אמר אביי משמש והולך (תהילים קטז) ושומר פתאים ה׳
>
> (Soncino translation)
>
> Our Rabbis taught: During **the first three months** marital intercourse is injurious to the woman and it is also injurious to the child. During **the middle ones** it is injurious to the woman but beneficial for the child. During **the last months** it is beneficial for both the woman and the child, since on account of it the child becomes well-formed and of strong vitality. One taught: He who indulges in marital intercourse on the ninetieth day is as though he had shed blood. But whence could one know this? - Rather, said Abaye, one carries on marital intercourse in the usual manner and the Lord preserveth the simple.

But primarily your reflex must be to ask a gynecologist as said @msh210 . In Halacha every issue which us linked to health should be discussed with a qualified physician.

Comment: Are you sure קשה means "injurious"?

Comment: @YK רש"י אומר לגבי קשה לאשה לא ידענא למאי
But concerning the Ubar, the central topic of the OP, it seems that it is really injurious. Anyway, medically speaking this is not a rare problem that in first trimester bleeding d/t intercourse occurs and the embryo is at risk, the woman should be treated with progestatives (not sure 100%)

May be also painfull. the libido of women is decreased in pregnancy, and especially at the beginning.

Comment: @YK not time to verify in Rishonim at the next hour, if you know that I have an error, pleas say it.

Comment: No, I don't know. I'm only wondering why you chose "injurious" instead of "difficulty" or something like that. I thought maybe you had a source.

Comment: @YK I simply pasted from Soncino, I am not English spocker

Answer (score 1):

Brown and Hershkovitz (here: [תשמיש בהריון](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/assia/tashmish-2.htm)-פסקה ז. דעת חז"ל) say that according to Chazal there is no problem having sexual intercourse during pregnancy, as long as there's an effective and permissible way of preventing fetal risk...

According to their words (of B&H) there are 2 main sources talking about the risks of having sexual intercourse during pregnancy:

1. same source as @kouty brought in his answer above. Regarding to that, it is important to note that most of the *poskim* think that *mitzvat* **עונה**-**conjugal rights**, which appears in Exodus 21:10- "If he take him another wife, her food, her raiment, and her **conjugal rights**, shall he not diminish") exists during the entire pregnancy as long as the wife wants it and it's for her own good.
2. Rabby Meir (Yebamoth 12b) which says that *"ג' נשים משמשות במוך. .. מעוברת - שמא יעשה עוברה סנדל"* (sorry, but I don't know how to translate it in appropriate way--maybe someone here can help); in simple words: having sexual intercourse during pregnant raising a risk of another impregnation, which puts the fetus under risk. However, *Rabanan* think that this risk is very low, and that is why people shouldn't do nothing about it (except saying *"מן השמיים ירחמו*")

Comment: ולד סנדל, is  foetus flatened, because of a second foetus which come after him, according to Rashi. this is not a problem with the intercourse but with the risk of a second pregancy, nowaday no such things exist.
literely sandal is. An example of co-ethymologi is a fish caled sole, and in Gemara sandal. sole is sandal

Comment: @kouty Thank you for your comment. I've changed  the relevant part of my answer. Just 2 things: 1. If I'm not missing anything- the risk of second pregnancy (another impregnation) is a result of having sexual intercourse during pregnancy; so, it does relates to having sexual intercourse during pregnant. 2. I'm not so sure that your claim of _nowday no such.._ is relevant, because I'm not so sure that the risk of having sexual intercourse during **the first three months** is relevant in our days.

Comment: May be that I was not clear. I want to say that nowadays if a pregnant woman has sexual intercourse, we are sure, according to hormono-physiology, that there will not be an additional ovulation and fecondation, despite the intercourse. So, intercourse has not the risk of fecondation according to the actual nature of human body

Comment: @kouty what about _Superfetation_?

Comment: ???accidental, isolated case reports